# How can I enhance my multiple sticky header

Tags: html, css

I have create a multiple sticky header:

```css
.content {
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center
}

.dataTable {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.dataTable thead {
  top: 36px;
}

.header {
  background: #ddd;
  color: #222;
  margin: 0px;
  position: sticky;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

#header01 {
  margin: 0px;
  top: 0;
}

.mainParent {
  background: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.10);
  text-align: center;
}

.mainParent {
  margin: 0em
}
```

```html
<div class="mainParent">
  <div class="header" id="header01">Header 01</div>
  <div id="content01" class="content">
    <table class="dataTable">
      <thead class="header">
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="dataTable">
      <thead class="header">
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>QQ</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

A gap exists between "Header01" and "1". When I scroll the page, the gap is disappeared.
So, how can I keep the gap between "Header01" and "1" when the page is scrolled?

Comment: For `.dataTable thead` set `top: 36px;` . You can also tune `top` and set `outline: 2px solid #fff;` to remove "hole" between 2 headers.